# Trouble understanding passing values and references in Python

Tags: python, oop, reference, pass-by-reference

Having issues with when objects are changed and when they aren't in Python. Here is my poorly contrived example below:

```
class person:
    age = 21

class bar:
    def __init__(self, arg1):
        self.foo = arg1
        self.foo.age = 23

def baz(arg1):
    arg1.age = 27

def teh(arg1):
    arg1 = [3,2,1]

Person1 = person()
bar1 = bar(Person1)

print Person1.age
print bar1.foo.age

baz(Person1)

print Person1.age
print bar1.foo.age

meh = [1,2,3]
teh(meh)
print meh
```

The output is

```
23
23
27
27
[1, 2, 3]
```

So when we declare Person1, Person1.age is 21. A reference to this object is passed to the class constructor of another class instance of bar, called bar1. Any changes made to this reference will change Person1.

This is also the case when we pass Person1 to a normal function, the Person1.age now equals 27.

But why doesn't this work on the variable "meh"? Certainly, if we assign a variable `a = meh` and change `a = [6, 6, 6]`, then meh will also be changed. I'm confused. Is there any literature on how all this works?

Comment: In order to get the proper code indentation in StackOverflow, you need to use spaces instead of tabulations.  It is also a good idea to do this in your own code, because that's what most people do in Python, I believe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can see three fundamental Python concepts that can shine some light on the question:

1) First, an assignment from a mutable object like in

```
self.foo = arg1
```

is like copying a pointer (and not the value pointed to): `self.foo` and `arg1` are the *same* object.  That's why the line that follows,

```
self.foo.age = 23
```

modifies `arg1` (i.e. `Person1`).  **Variables are thus different "names" or "labels" that can point to a unique object** (here, a `person` object).  This explains why `baz(Person1)` modifies `Person1.age` *and* `bar1.foo.age` to 27, since `Person1` and `bar1.foo` are just two names for the *same* `person` object (`Person1 is bar1.foo` returns `True`, in Python).

2) The second important notion is that of assignments.  In

```
def teh(arg1):
    arg1 = [3,2,1]
```

variable `arg1` is local, so that the code

```
meh = [1,2,3]
teh(meh)
```

first does `arg1 = meh`, which means that `arg1` is an additional (local) name for list `meh`; but doing `arg1 = [3, 2, 1]` is like  saying "I changed my mind: `arg1` will from now on be the name of a *new* list, [3, 2, 1]".  The important thing to keep in mind here is that **assignments, despite being denoted with an "equal" sign, are asymmetrical**: they give to a (mutable) object on the right-and-side an additional name, given in the left-hand side (that's why you can't do `[3, 2, 1] = arg1`, as the left-hand side must be a name [or names]).  So, `arg1 = meh; arg1 = [3, 2, 1]` cannot change `meh`.

3) The last point is related to the question title: "passing by value" and "passing by reference" are not concepts that are relevant in Python.  The relevant concepts are instead "**mutable object**" and "**immutable object**".  Lists are mutable, while numbers are not, which explains what you observe.  Also, your `Person1` and `bar1` objects are mutable (that's why you can change the person's age).  You can find more information about these notions in a [text tutorial](http://www.pythontutorials.net/advanced-python-function.aspx) and a [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wlB4FXZGXKU).  Wikipedia also has some [(more technical) information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).  An example illustrates the difference of behavior between mutable and immutable:

```
x = (4, 2)
y = x  # This is equivalent to copying the value (4, 2), because tuples are immutable
y += (1, 2, 3)  # This does not change x, because tuples are immutable; this does y = (4, 2) + (1, 2, 3)

x = [4, 2]
y = x  # This is equivalent to copying a pointer to the [4, 2] list
y += [1, 2, 3]  # This also changes x, because x and y are different names for the same (mutable) object
```

The last line is *not* equivalent to `y = y + [1, 2, 3]` because this would only put a new list object in variable `y` instead of changing the list referred to by both `y` and `x`.

The three concepts above (variables as names [for mutable objects], asymmetrical assignment, and mutability/immutability) explain many of Python's behaviors.

Comment: "Mutable object" vs. "immutable object" really is not very relevant here; the issue is "mutation" vs. "assignment". `arg1` can be used to mutate `meh`, but it can't be used to assign a new value to `meh`.

Comment: @ruakh: It is true that the code in the question is only about assignment and mutability; however, the title is about "passing by value and reference", so I think that it is anyway useful to mention the Python's approach to the  modification (or not) of variables passed by the caller (i.e. mutable and immutable objects).

Comment: @ruakh: PS: I did update my post, though, so as to deemphasize the mutability vs immutability aspect.

Answer (score 6):

> Certainly, if we assign a variable a = meh and change a = [6, 6, 6], then meh will also be changed.

No, actually, it won't:

```
>>> meh = [1,2,3]
>>> a = meh
>>> a = [6, 6, 6]
>>> print a
[6, 6, 6]
>>> print meh
[1, 2, 3]
```

It's the difference between *overwriting* a variable and *modifying* the instance *pointed to* by a variable.

Lists, dictionaries, sets, and objects are mutable types. If you add, remove, set, get, or otherwise modify something *in* an instance of them, it updates everything that references that instance.

If, however, you assign a completely **new instance** of the type to a variable, that changes the reference stored in that variable, and thus the old referenced instance is not changed.

---

```
a = [1,2,3] # New instance
a[1] = 4    # Modifying existing instance

b = {'x':1, 'y':2} # New instance
b['x'] = 3         # Modifying existing instance

self.x = [1,2,3] # Modifying existing object instance pointed to by 'self',
                 # and creating new instance of a list to store in 'self.x'

self.x[0] = 5    # Modifying existing list instance pointed to by 'self.x'
```

Answer (score 0):

Python does not have pass-by-value, nor pass-by-reference, but instead uses pass-by-object -- in other words, objects are passed directly into functions, and bound to the parameter name given in the function definition.

When you do spam = "green", you have bound the name spam to the string object "green"; if you then do eggs = spam you have not copied anything, you have not made reference pointers; you have simply bound another name, eggs, to the same object ("green" in this case). If you then bind spam to something else (spam = 3.14159) eggs will still be bound to "green".

In your `teh` function you are not changing/modifying/mutating the passed in object, you are reassigning the name `arg1` to a different list.  To change `arg1` you want this:

```
def teh(arg1):
    arg1[:] = [3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: "Pass by name" (or "call by name") is an entirely different thing, see http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~cameron/Teaching/383/PassByName.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_name. Python's argument passing model is instead described as "call by sharing", and in other languages with the same argument passing, it's considered call by value with the value always being a pointer/reference to an object.

Comment: @delnan: Thanks, updated to 'call-by-object'.  Python does not expose the underlying mechanics used to implement call-by-object, so using the term 'call-by-value' is harmful.