# A numpy array unexpectedly changes when changing another one despite being separate

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I found a bug in my large code, and I simplified the issue to the case below.

Although in each step I only change `w2`, but when at each step I print out `w1`, it is also changed, because end of the first loop I assign them to be equal.
I read for this but there was written in case I make `w1 = w2[:]` it will solve the issue but it does not

```
import numpy as np
import math

w1=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
w2=np.zeros_like(w1)
print 'w1=',w1
for n in range(0,3):
    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            print 'n=',n,'i=',i,'j=',j,'w1=',w1
            w2[i,j]=w1[i,j]*2

    w1=w2[:]


#Simple tests
# w=w2[:]
# w1=w[:]

# p=[1,2,3]
# q=p[:];
# q[1]=0;
# print p
```

Comment: You're assigning a copy of `w2` to `w1` each time, only after modifying `w1`, correct?  But you don't expect `w1` to remain `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`, do you?

Comment: Why not just do `w2 = w1 * 2`?

Comment: Ugh, yes, thanks @Suever -- let's take a step back: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I start with initial values for w1, then in loops at each step of n I assign values to w2, and when I did for its all elements then I feed it in to w1, and make w1 equal to that. but when for the first time I do this(i.e. w1=w2), whenever I change w2 during loop w1 changes as well immediately.

Comment: @BrianCain the reason for that is just I want to make an example of my code, there it is more complicated. okay.
take w2[i,j]=w1[i,j]+(2*i+j)
instead

Comment: @Soheilsmz yes because you need to assign the *values* of `w2` into `w1`. As it is, you are simply pointing `w1` and `w2` to the same underlying object.

Comment: @Suever I know it is because of that. but dont know how to avoid that! any solutions

Comment: @Soheilsmz just posted two options that should work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. Why is this and how can I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-why-is-this-and-how-can-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue is that when you're assigning values back to `w1` from `w2` you aren't actually passing the values from `w1` to `w2`, but rather you are actually pointing the two variables at the *same object*.

**The issue you are having**

```
w1 = np.array([1,2,3])
w2 = w1

w2[0] = 3

print(w2)   # [3 2 3]
print(w1)   # [3 2 3]

np.may_share_memory(w2, w1)  # True
```

**The Solution**

Instead you will want to copy over the *values*. There are two common ways of doing this with numpy arrays.

```
w1 = numpy.copy(w2)
w1[:] = w2[:]
```

Demonstration

```
w1 = np.array([1,2,3])
w2 = np.zeros_like(w1)

w2[:] = w1[:]

w2[0] = 3

print(w2)   # [3 2 3]
print(w1)   # [1 2 3]

np.may_share_memory(w2, w1)   # False
```

Comment: Thank you, that is my mistake

Comment: Do you assert that `w1=w2[:]` makes them point to the same object? It's not like this with `list`s.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Yes this is correct. Typically a numpy array created simply using an indexing operation (such as `w2[:]`) is simply a different "view" of the same underlying data in memory. This can be verified using [`numpy.may_share_memory(w1, w2)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.may_share_memory.html)

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev [here is a great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18808601/670206) that goes over some of the finer points of memory management in numpy