# Python copy of array also changes normal array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have an 2D array called 'arr' which I copy but when I change the copy it also changes the original.
Code:

```
def play(arr):

    for row in range(len(arr)):
        for column in range(len(arr[row])):
            if arr[row][column] == '':
                tempArr = arr.copy()
                tempArr[row][column] = 'a'

    print(arr)

play([['', ''], ['', '']])
```

Output:

```
[['a' 'a']
 ['a' 'a']]
```

Expected output:

```
[['' '']
 ['' '']]
```

But this doesn't happen if in a 1D array:

```
def play(arr):

    for row in range(len(arr)):
            if arr[row] == '':
                tempArr = arr.copy()
                tempArr[row] = 'a'

    print(arr)
    print('Temp arr: ' + str(arr))

play(['', ''])
```

Output:

```
['' '']
tempArr: ['' 'a']
```

What can I do about this?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A numpy array unexpectedly changes when changing another one despite being separate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978165/a-numpy-array-unexpectedly-changes-when-changing-another-one-despite-being-separ)

Comment: @AlexandreB. Thanks for your comment but it is not a duplicate since I am already using `arr.copy()` and not using numpy arrrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy method do not recursively copy the nested structures in a list. To achieve this you need to do a deepcopy. Try this in your code :

```
import copy
tempArr = copy.deepcopy(arr)
```