# Data security of an instance after passing it to another instance in Python

Tags: python, oop

I create an instance of class `A`, `objA1` whose `objA1.data` stored something to be processed later.
Then I create an instance of class `B`, `objB1`, by passing `objA1` into the instance constructor:

```
objB1 = B(objA1...)
```

`objA1` is assigned to an attribute of `objB1`:

```
objB1.obj = objA1
```

Afterwards, a method of `objB1` is called to process `objB1.obj.data`.
`objB1.obj.data` is modified by the method doubtlessly.
But is `objA1.data` modified at the same time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble understanding passing values and references in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838005/trouble-understanding-passing-values-and-references-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

If the data is [immutable](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) *(like a string, tuple)* you are safe, but if, for example is [mutable](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) *(like a list, dict)*, yes the data passed by reference may be [modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838005/trouble-understanding-passing-values-and-references-in-python). Let's make an example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = ['important']

class B:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj

    def unsafe(self):
        data = self.obj.data
        # process data
        data[0] = 'nothing here'

objA1 = A()
print objA1.data    # ['important']

objB1 = B(objA1)
objB1.unsafe()
print objA1.data    # ['nothing here']
```

### Back to Safety

You could just make a copy before processing. You need to import [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html):

```
import copy
```

Now you can use [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) in the method `__init__` of class `B` like this:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = copy.deepcopy(obj)
```

Let's try again:

```
objA1 = A()
print objA1.data    # ['important']

objB1 = B(objA1)
objB1.unsafe()
print objA1.data    # ['important']
```

*The important data is safe!*

You can also create a `safe` method in `B` and copy only `data`. Here a [*shallow copy*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.copy) may suffice:

```
class B:
    # ...
    def safe(self):
        data = copy.copy(self.obj.data)
        # process data
        data[0] = 'nothing here'
```